# Attach an event handler to an object literal

Tags: javascript

I have an object literal to open a websocket connection. this is a simplified version of it:

```
const ws = {

    conn : null,

    start : function(){
            
            this.conn = new WebSocket('wss://.....');

            this.conn.onopen = (e) => {};   

            this.conn.onmessage = (e) => {};    
                
            this.conn.onclose = (e) => {};  
                    
        }
}
```

i can initialize the connection with:

```
var websocket = ws.start();
```

now i want to attach an eventhandler to *websocket*, which is called when *onmessage* is fired. like this:

```
websocket.on('message', function (e) {

    console.log('this.conn.onmessage in ws was fired');

});
```

is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the connection at the end of the `start` function.

```js
const ws = {

    conn : null,

    start : function(){
            
            this.conn = new WebSocket('wss://.....');

            this.conn.onopen = (e) => {};   

            this.conn.onmessage = (e) => {};    
                
            this.conn.onclose = (e) => {};  
                    
            return this.conn;
        }
}
```

Comment: But i need the onmessage() handler inside of _ws_ AND outside. and when i do `websocket.onmessage = (m) => {}`, the _this.conn.onmessage_ gets overwritten

Comment: @fx123 just don't assign directly to `onmessage`, call `on("message", ...)` (_like you're doing in your example_) to have multiple listeners

Comment: Great! Thx for your help! `websocket.addEventListener('message', function....` works!

Answer (score 1):

You can return the websocket at the end of the `start` function.

```js
start: function() {
    this.conn = new WebSocket('wss://.....');
    this.conn.onopen = (e) => {};
    this.conn.onmessage = (e) => {};
    this.conn.onclose = (e) => {};
    return this.conn;
}
```